# x-editable combodate dynamic date

Tags: jquery, x-editable

I have a field of type combodate with x-editable. When I load a new record from ajax, I try to destroy the instance and replace the value and recreate the instance.

```
<a href="#" id="pdob" data-type="combodate"  data-template="MMM / D / YYYY" data-format="YYYY-MM-DD" data-viewformat="MM/DD/YYYY" data-pk="1" data-title="Select Date of birth" class="pk"></a>

$('#pdob').attr("data-value", p.pdob);
    $('#pdob').editable("destroy").editable({
        combodate: {
            minYear: 1920,
        },
        url: 'ajax/updatePatientField.php',
        emptytext: 'Click To Add',
});
```

When I run this part again with the new p.pdob, it does not update. My data-value gets changed but the text is still the old date and when I click on it, it shows the old date in the dropdowns.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

please try `setValue` with third parameter `true` - it means convert str to internal format (e.g. `Date` object)

```
$('#myDate').editable('setValue', '03-04-2016', true);
```